# javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'textv' for locale 'pl_PL'

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I started learn spring and when I want to add internationalization to my project, I got that error.

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'textv'
>   for locale 'pl_PL'.

type Exception report

```
message javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'textv' for locale 'pl_PL'.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'textv'
 for locale 'pl_PL'.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:591)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 root cause

 javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No
 message found under code 'textv' for locale 'pl_PL'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 root cause

 javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'textv'
 for locale 'pl_PL'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(index_jsp.java:150)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:108)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

What I use:

```
 1. Netbeans
 2. Maven 
 3. Spring 4.2.1
 4. Tomcat 8
```

This is my project structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ9xq.png

Servlet configuration class

```
public class WebXmlConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{ApplicationConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

This is my spring config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.exercises.spring.springproject03")
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    registry.viewResolver(getInternalResourceViewResolver());
}


@Bean
public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pdfs/**").addResourceLocations("/pdfs/");

}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("locale");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.exercises.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>springproject03</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springproject03</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>springproject02</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>SprinfBlogWebApp</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page session="false" language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib  prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib  prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><spring:message code="textv" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>${msg}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should work but it doesn't. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

It takes me so long to find my mistake, but solution was simple. The only thing to do was to add bean name on message source bean.

```
@Bean(name ="messageSource")
public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: +1 you saved my day. I know I had to add the `id` from xml, but the auto completion kept saying that `id` was invalid. And removing it kept throwing the error mentioned by OP. So its `name`! Thank you!!